# Laptop just restarts when trying to install any linux partition

Tags: linux, boot, laptop, reboot

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430. When I got it, it had Windows 7, but I installed kali linux. Everything worked perfectly until one day I tried to boot my pc and it just made a beep sound and restarted. I went to install Windows 10 from a usb stick and everything worked fine. Today I tried to install Ubuntu, without success. I tried to use "try ubuntu", my laptop just restarted after a few seconds of black screen, same with the install ubuntu option. So I went back to windows and got openSUSE Tumbleweed, exactly the same problem, just won't install, it just restarts.

EDIT: The install option just worked for openSUSE Tumbleweed, but then my screen was full of vertical white bars, made a beep and restarted.

SOLUTION: I just started the Linux distrobution with -nodemodeset boot parameter.

Comment: Multiple OSes all have random restarts - hardware issue of some sort.  I suggest doing a complete shutdown holding down the power button for 10 seconds, waiting a bit, starting it and holding down F10, and running the hardware diagnostics.  I've never used the Lenovo diagnostics, but if you can leave it on the menu screen for half an hour without issue, that's a good data point.  Then, run the diagnostics, including the long memory test if offered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting the linux distrobution with the -nomodeset boot paramter helped for me.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.